# How do I have padding at the bottom of my UITextView like in Mail.app so the text isn't scrunched?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview

In Mail.app, if I go to create a new message and type all the way so the text is at the last line of the UITextView there is still a decent amount of space between the last line of text and the keyboard if you scroll down. But you can't type here. It's just nice padding so you can read it without it being scrunched against the keyboard, and if you select the text, the selection handles don't extend under the keyboard.

My question is, how do I mimic this with a traditional UITextView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do this by setting the contentInset property of your UITextView:

```
myTextView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-4,-8,0,0);
```

btw... the values above are not specific to your situation. You will want to adjust these to get the inset you are looking for.